# How to mount a drive for other user than root?

Tags: mount, root

I've attached a SSD disk though USB.
Then:

```
 sudo su -
 mkdir /mnt/hx
 chown ondra /mnt/hx
 mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hx  # It's FAT32 now, but was the same with EXT4
```

The last command changes dir owner to root.
Whenever I create a file in the root dir, I need to be root and root is the owner.

Can I set different user as owner of the mounted dir?
Or, simply said, ensure that user XY can freely read/write on the drive.

Comment: Why don't you just `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/hx` then `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/hx`?

Comment: Seems like it's the  uid=1000,gid=1000 options

Comment: You gotta do a `sudo chown -R username:groupname /folder`. The `-R` makes the chown permissions be applied recursively. Also check the `chmod`, even that takes the `-R` parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Gnome-based GUI environment

```
gio mount -d /dev/sdb1
```

Easy as that.

For older versions of Gnome you may need to use `gvfs-mount` instead:

```
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1
```

### Headless (no GUI) machine

Add an entry in `/etc/fstab` and specify options for it.

From the manpage of `fstab`:

```
   The fourth field (fs_mntops).
          This field describes the mount options associated with the filesystem.

          <snip>

          user   allow a user to mount
          owner  allow device owner to mount
```

Now you'll need to make sure the device is owned by the correct owner. Specify that in an `udev` rule. Put a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-myhdd-ownerchange.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0ff9", MODE="0600", OWNER="username"
```

Replace the vendor and product ids with the USB device you want to get triggered by it. Find them using the command `lsusb`. Also change the `MODE` if you like.

Alternatively, use [`pmount`](http://pmount.alioth.debian.org/). I don't like it, personally.

Comment: I have mounted it succesfully. But now I can't exec executable files, not even with `exec` amongst options.

Comment: @OndraŽižka Are you sure about the order of options you gave in the fourth field? The example in the manpage mentions ``user,exec``. AFAIK if you would do ``exec,user``, then ``user`` will override the ``exec`` option with its implication ``noexec``. If it still does not work, please share the relevant line in ``/proc/mounts``.

Comment: +1 for pmount, I didn't have any luck with gvfs.

Comment: `gvfs-mount` has been replaced with `gio mount` in current versions of Gnome.

Comment: @DavidKennedy Thanks, added.